# Page template for all WooCommerce Files

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a page template that is a minimalized page (call it min-page.php) in my theme. I use it to remove the header and footer info and add in some basic links so the customer doesn't get distracted.

I can change this template in the Page Attributes on various WooCommerce pages (checkout, cart, my account) but I can't change it on the product page or the general shopping page that displays all the products.

How can I set these pages to use my page template?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the single product template by using the following code via `functions.php`

```
function get_product_template($single_template) {
 global $post;

 if ($post->post_type == 'product') {
      $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/min-page.php';
 }
 return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_product_template' );
```

Check the template path after placing the code.